# anti-aliased circle is jagged in opencv

Tags: opencv, graphics

It may seem like a common OpenCV recipe for a circle yields really jagged edges to the circles being drawn. Here's minimally viable reproducible code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8) 
cv2.circle(image, (350, 350), 200, (15,75,50), cv2.FILLED)
cv2.imshow("Circle", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: image of jagged circle circumference]

It's perhaps a little better in the case of a non-filled circle (when using `lineType=cv2.LINE_AA`):

[image: similar to previous]

But it's sometimes nice to draw circles which are both filled and have a good edge to their circumference at the same time.

I wonder if this outcome can be improved within the framework of using OpenCV, even though OpenCV probably does not try to be a pixel perfect drawing library.

Thanks in advance for your help as I narrow down my choice between OpenCV and Pyglet for a certain *computer vision with graphics* implementation. And also because it would be nice to have visually pleasing conventional shapes even for just your haphazard use of shape drawing in some OpenCV laden applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **both** `thickness=cv.FILLED` **and** `lineType=cv.LINE_AA` in the same call.

You should always consult the documentation of the technologies you use.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8) 
cv2.circle(image, (350, 350), 200, (15,75,50), thickness=cv2.FILLED, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("Circle", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```